# Pandas: How to get the count of each value in a column with groupby option

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is the dataframe I've got:

```
data = {'Year' : [2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022], 
        'Class':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C'], 
        'Animal':['dog|cat|bird', 'cat|dog', 'tiger|dog', 'cat|bird', 'dog|cat|rabbit', 'rabbit|dog|tiger',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So the df looks like:

| Year | Class | Animal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | A | dog|cat|bird |
| 2021 | A | cat|dog |
| 2021 | B | tiger|dog |
| 2022 | A | cat|bird |
| 2022 | C | dog|cat|rabbit |
| 2022 | C | rabbit|dog|tiger |

What I'd like to do is to calculate the number of each animal in each year and class. For example, I want to get the following dataframe:

| Year | Class | Animal | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | A | dog | 2 |
| 2021 | A | cat | 2 |
| 2021 | A | bird | 1 |
| 2021 | B | tiger | 1 |
| 2021 | B | dog | 1 |
| 2022 | A | cat | 1 |
| 2022 | A | bird | 1 |
| 2022 | C | dog | 2 |
| 2022 | C | cat | 1 |
| 2022 | C | rabbit | 2 |
| 2022 | C | tiger | 1 |

Does anyone have any suggestions about achieving this? I'd be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a one-liner:

```
(df.assign(Animal=df['Animal'].str.split('|'))     # Create a list using split
  .explode('Animal')                               # Expand that list it rows using explode
  .value_counts(sort=False)                        # Use pd.DataFrame.value_counts 
  .rename('Count')                                 # Rename series
  .reset_index())                                  # Reset to a dataframe
```

Output:

```
    Year Class  Animal  Count
0   2021     A    bird      1
1   2021     A     cat      2
2   2021     A     dog      2
3   2021     B     dog      1
4   2021     B   tiger      1
5   2022     A    bird      1
6   2022     A     cat      1
7   2022     C     cat      1
8   2022     C     dog      2
9   2022     C  rabbit      2
10  2022     C   tiger      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `str.get_dummies` then `groupby`

```
out = (df.Animal.str.get_dummies('|')
       .groupby([df['Year'],df['Class']]).sum()
       .mask(lambda x : x==0)
       .rename_axis(['animal'],axis=1).stack().reset_index(name='Count')
Out[666]: 
    Year Class  animal  Count
0   2021     A    bird    1.0
1   2021     A     cat    2.0
2   2021     A     dog    2.0
3   2021     B     dog    1.0
4   2021     B   tiger    1.0
5   2022     A    bird    1.0
6   2022     A     cat    1.0
7   2022     C     cat    1.0
8   2022     C     dog    2.0
9   2022     C  rabbit    2.0
10  2022     C   tiger    1.0
```